# Javascript: How to "GET" value from dynamic generate input

Tags: javascript

i use php to generate dynamic input, example generated code

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' name='name1' onBlur='getValue(1)'>
<input type='text' name='name2' onBlur='getValue(2)'>
<input type='text' name='name3' onBlur='getValue(3)'>
<input type='text' name='name4' onBlur='getValue(4)'>
<input type='text' name='name5' onBlur='getValue(5)'>
```

or more....

**Javascript**

```
function getValue(x){
    var nam = document.myForm.name[x].value;  <<< error?
    if(nam>1000){
        document.myForm.name[x].focus;   <<< error?
        alert ("input > 1000");
    }
}
```

What the right way to code the javascript? which i pointed <<< error?

Thanks

Comment: inline js is evil. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qfFdm/)

```
function getValue(nameValue){
    var element = document.getElementsByName('name' + nameValue)[0];
    if(element){
       if(parseInt(element.value, 10) > 1000){
           setTimeout(function(){
              element.focus();
           },0);  
           alert ("input > 1000");
       }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
getValue(1);
```

Comment: Gabe, thanks your's working example is working fine but once i implement your code into my project, the focus is not working, it always show the next object when i using "Tab"

Comment: In what browser does the focus not work. I only tested in chrome.

Comment: @user1493339... Check out my updated answer. Should fix the focus issue. http://jsfiddle.net/qfFdm/ ... Tested in Chrome, FF, IE7, IE8 and IE9

Comment: i believe your way is collect, just it not working, my previous project i also code like "document.myForm.NAMEX.focus;" and it work but this time, this project is  not working, same pc, same browser (firefox and chorme) but the way your working example's focus is working fine..... same browser with different tabs only!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, the above code is the solution, clearly.

Answer (score 0):

`document.myForm.name['name'+x].value;` and `document.myForm.name['name'+x].focus()`

Comment: why have 2 name?
document.myForm.**name**['**name**'+x].value;

Comment: Your code is `<input ... name='name1' ... />`, so the name of the element is 'name1', not '1'.  In your question, you are trying to find the element with the name "1", but your element's name is "name1", not "1".  Make sense?

Comment: oh i see, so the 1st name is a reserve word "name", then my 2nd name (inside the blanket) is my name of input......
am i right!?